# How to delete everything except top-level numeric directories?

Tags: find, zsh, wildcards

I want to delete everything under some directory `/path/to/foo`, EXCEPT those sub-directories that match the meta-pattern

```
/path/to/foo/<DIGITS>/
```

For example, if the contents under `/path/to/foo` are initially like this:

```
/path/to/foo
├── 0/
│   ├── a
│   └── b
├── 232532/
├── 42
├── 73/
│   ├── d
│   └── e
├── 8xyz/
│   ├── i
│   └── j
├── _bar/
│   ├── x
│   ├── y
│   └── z
├── .baz/
│   ├── f
│   └── frobozz/
│       ├── g
│       └── h
└── quux/
    └── 123/
```

...I want to end up with

```
/path/to/foo
├── 0/
│   ├── a
│   └── b
├── 232532/
└── 73/
    ├── d
    └── e
```

I'm looking for a `find ... -delete`-based incantation, or a suitable `zsh` glob pattern (for `rm -r`), that will do this. I am using Linux.

Comment: @JeffSchaller no, that will just retouch the directory you created before. Just use: `mkdir -p 0/{a,b} 232532 73/{d,e} 8xyz/{i,j} _bar/{x,y,z} .baz/f .baz/frobozz/{g,h} quux/123; touch 42`

Comment: @terdon: I'm using Debian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
rm -rf /path/to/foo/^<->(D) /path/to/foo/<->(^-/)
```

- `^something` is *not something* (similar to `ksh`'s `!(something)`)
- `<->` is `<x-y>` to match decimal integers from `x` to `y`, but with none of the bounds provided (so matches any sequence of decimal digits, similar to `ksh`'s `+([0-9])`).
- `(D)` a glob qualifier to include hidden files (`D`ot files)
- `(^-/)` a glob qualifier to say *only files that are not of type directory after symlink resolution* (remove the `-` if you also want to remove symlinks to directories).

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to GNU `find`, you can run:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not \( -type d -regex '.*/[0-9]*$' \) -exec rm -r {} +
```

The idea is to find those top level files that aren't i) directories and ii) whose name doesn't consist of nothing but numbers.

I strongly urge you to run it once with `echo` instead of `rm -r` to see what it will do.

Answer (score 4):

```
cd /path/to/foo && \
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -delete -o \
   ! -name . -name '*[!0-9]*' -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Which reads as:

- change over to the /path/to/foo directory and once successfully there
- invoke `find` to go just one level deep and delete any non-directories there.
- for all others, i.e., subdirectories in your /path/to/foo dir, reject those with the names of ".", and what remains out of these, select those that have at least one nondigit in it.
- The selected dirs are then led to the abbatoir, thereby ensuring the survival of digit-only dirs.

Answer (score 3):

[Apart from zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384768), you can't select non-directories using wildcards (you can only make a wildcard pattern apply to all file types, or apply to directories and symlinks to directories by putting a `/` at the end).

In any shell, you can loop over the files and exclude the ones you want to keep. To enumerate all files including dot files and `.` and `..`, use the two wildcard patterns `* .*`. It's possible that `*` will not match any file and so will remain unexpanded; in this case, `rm -rf` is executed on `*`, which does nothing since `rm -f` ignores non-existent arguments.

```
for x in * .*; do
  case "$x" in
    .|..: continue;;                              # skip the . and .. entries
    *[!0-9]*) rm -rf -- "$x";;                    # not just digits -> delete
    *) if ! [ -d "$x" ]; then rm -f -- "$x"; fi   # just digits -> delete if not a directory
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find ./* ! \( -type d -regex "./[0-9]+\(/.*\)?" \) -delete
```

or, if `foo` have too many files and the argument limit excess happens, use:

```
find . ! -path . ! \( -type d -regex "./[0-9]+\(/.*\)?" \) -delete
```